# Share the same database content between multiple view components?

Tags: database, performance, asp.net-core, model, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have an ASP.NET Core project. It contains multiple view components on the same razor page:

```
<div class="row">
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("IndexKategori", new { viewName = "IndexKategori" })
    <aside class="col-md-4 right-sidebar-lg" style="height: auto !important;">
        <div class="sticky">
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("PopularPost", new { viewName = "PopularPost" })
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("SonEklenenler", new { viewName = "SonEklenenler" })
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("YorumSide", new { viewName = "YorumSide" })
        </div>
    </aside>
    <div class="col-12 mb-4">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("IndexKonu")
    </div>
</div>
```

All of these view components request data from the same database table. I want to know: Can I use a single request for all view components in order to improve performance and reduce duplicate queries? If yes, how?

[image: I prepared a scheme to explain my purpose]

Comment: `can I use a single request for all view components for performance?`.What do you mean?Can you give me a detailed explanation.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly if you mean that each of your components make a separate database request, and that you would like to reduce that to a single database request and then make the data available to all of your different components?

Comment: Actually, this is a news portal. Most of the view components get data from the news table in the database. I mean, can I use all the data I need on a page with a single query and use it from this data pool I have created for all view components?